# D3 Weapon Damage Physical Damage

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I have This weapon below, and it has "Fire Damage". My build is all Physical damage. I want to roll the Fire Damage for Physical damage, however that's not an options.. Is it regular damage, or how does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**+X-Y Damage** is indeed Physical damage, but you shouldn't care anyway.

For several patches, Blizzard has gradually removed the interaction between weapon bonus element and skill element. Currently weapon element does not matter **at all**.

Every skill converts all weapon damage to element of the skill. The only point in rerolling is increasing the +damage roll range itself, and you can pick any element that rolls.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I guess I'll just reroll the damage and hope to hit max